# Can i get an event for the currently visible text in quill?

Tags: javascript, quill

i'm interested in providing secondary information elsewhere in the document - e.g. as you scroll through a document in Quill, another text area shows the number of capitalized words in the *visible* part of the document. I'm not concerned here with visible in the sense of a partly obscured window, nor even in the case that the Quill text input area is partly obscured, e.g. by scrolling the document, but only in what text of the document is shown in the Quill editing area - it might e.g. be just part of one very long line.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I understand you wrong, so you wanna be able to search through the Text that someone writes in the Quill Editor and get Feedback based on that for example how many Capitalized Letters it contains?

They have a Method to get the Content as a String:

> **getText**
>
> Retrieves the string contents of the editor.

[More about that function](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#gettext)

Note that the Editor shows you only text but in the background works with HTML Tags for example if you type in a Word and Select H1 then it generates you `<h1>Word</h1>` so keep that in mind when you try to analyse the string for certain things.

Comment: Thank you for replying. No, i only want to search the part of the text that's visible. if it's a long file and there are only three paragraphs visible, I want to search in just those three paragraphs.